# Client Requesition to server using server ip address

Tags: webserver, ip, firewall

I was told to do something I don't believe is possible, that challenge is as follows.

I have 2 web servers.

Web Server 1 is where the pages are and clients access it, server 2 is a server with a very restrictive firewall setting which is to only accept access from server 1.

So, server 1 has a link of a content inside server 2, and it can only be accessed if the request comes from the server 1 Ip address.

But, the client cliks the link therefore his IP address will be sent to server 2, which will be denied because the firewall policy.

Am I getting this correctly or there's a way to do this?

I hope you can understand what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what the person posing this problem to you is suggesting is that the client connects to server 1, then server 1 connects to server 2 to fetch the content (i.e server-to-server, on the fly, perhaps by way of some API).  So, the client never connects to server 2 directly.

```
client --> server 1 --> server 2
```

Comment: Yes, kind of a very simple structure, I'll wait a little more to see what kind of application these servers are going to run, but thanks a lot for your reply, now I know it's possible and it's not that tricky.